# templates value `defValue' cannot appear in a constant- expression

Tags: c++, templates

As i understood, template value need to be known in compilation time.
so i write a little example just to see that i get it, but apperantly i didn't.
so i get this:

```
`defValue' cannot appear in a constant-
 expression
```

can anyone please what is the problem and how it can be fixed?

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T,T defaultVal, int dim=255>
class Vec
{
    T _vec[dim];
    int _dim;
    public:
    Vec () : _dim(dim)
    {
       for (int i=0;i<_dim;++i)
       {
         _vec[i] = defaultVal;
       }
    }
    ~Vec () {};
// other operators and stuff
};

int main ()
{
    int defValue = 0;
    Vec < int,defValue > vecWithDefVal;// here is the problem but i don't know why
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++03 14.3.2

> Template non-type arguments
>
> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> —  an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
>
> —  the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
>
> —  the  address  of  an  object  or  function  with  external  linkage,  including  function  templates  and  function
> template-ids  but  excluding  non-static  class  members,  expressed  as  & id-expression  where  the  & is
> optional if the name refers to a function or array, or if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> —  a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1 .

`defValue` [being a non-type argument] is neither of the above.

Change `int defValue = 0;` to `const int defValue = 0` and your code will compile [see the first condition].

Or directly write `Vec <int,0> vecWithDefVal;`

Answer (score 1):

Templates can only be parametrised by types and compile-time constants of basic types.  So `Vec < int,0 > vecWithDefVal;` would be ok.